# Query that removes a duplicate entry using mysql

Tags: mysql, database

My target is to create a query that removes a duplicate entry in a row using MySQL 5.7. My current function matches entries with the same weight however, it has a duplicate. (Please, see the 2nd table)

Here is my entry table.

```
entryID| entryName  | weight |
-------------------------------
1      | lamok2     | 1970 |
2      | lamok2     | 1955 |
3      | lamok3     | 1965 |
4      | lamok3     | 1975 |
5      | lamok3     | 1985 |
6      | lamok4     | 1955 |
7      | lamok4     | 1960 |
8      | lamok4     | 1975 |
9      | lamok5     | 1955 |
10     | MA1        | 2000 |
11     | MA2        | 2010 |
```

After applying my query which is:

```
SELECT t1.entryName  AS mname, t1.weight AS weight,
        MIN(t2.entryName) AS wname,MIN(t2.weight) AS weight
FROM entry t1
LEFT JOIN entry t2 ON t1.weight = t2.weight AND t1.entryName != t2.entryName
GROUP BY t1.entryID, t1.entryName, t1.weight

it produces this:

mname| weight | wname  | weight| 
--------------------------------------------
lamok2 | 1970 | NULL   | NULL   |
lamok2 | 1955 | lamok4 | 1955   |
lamok3 | 1965 | NULL   | NULL   |
lamok3 | 1975 | lamok4 | 1975   |
lamok3 | 1985 | NULL   | NULL   |
lamok4 | 1955 | lamok2 | 1955   |
lamok4 | 1960 | NULL   | NULL   |
lamok4 | 1975 | lamok3 | 1975   |
lamok5 | 1955 | lamok2 | 1955   |
MA1    | 2000 | NULL   | NULL   |
MA2    | 2010 | NULL   | NULL   |
```

As we can see on the result, `Lamok 2 and Lamok 4 had a 2 matches` `Lamok 3 and Lamok 4 had a 2 matches too`... It shouldn't be possible... This is counted as the duplicate fight. How can I avoid this kind of duplication in my query?

This is my target output: (No duplicate fights)

```
 mname| weight | wname  | weight| 
    --------------------------------------------
    lamok2 | 1970 | NULL   | NULL   |
    lamok2 | 1955 | lamok4 | 1955   |
    lamok3 | 1965 | NULL   | NULL   |
    lamok3 | 1975 | lamok4 | 1975   |
    lamok3 | 1985 | NULL   | NULL   |
    lamok4 | 1960 | NULL   | NULL   |
    lamok5 | 1955 | lamok2 | 1955   |
    MA1    | 2000 | NULL   | NULL   |
    MA2    | 2010 | NULL   | NULL   |
```

Comment: What is the logic behind the query?

Comment: What's your expected result?

Comment: I'm sorry, the logic behind my query is to match entries with the same weight. However, in my current function same weight works but it has a duplicate fight. As we can see lamok 2 and lamok 4 had 2 matches. also Lamok 3 and 4. It should be only 1 match and duplicate should not happen. Thank you in advance for commenting ^_^

Comment: I'm newbie to this. With all due respect, is it okay for me to ask you to revise my code? Thank you. Appreciated.

Comment: What is the linking criteria? Why `lamok4 | 1955` is linked with `lamok2 | 1955` but is not linked with `lamok5 | 1955`?

Comment: Because first come first serve, I forgot to add dateCreated. But it's one of the basis. Based on the table, lamok 2 and lamok 4 comes before lamok 5. That's why it prioritizes the first entries. (I'm sorry if it's confusing. Thankyou)

Comment: Do amend your question to include new information.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need group by two columns, by `entryName` and `weight`.

So this query will return your duplicates:

```
SELECT *
FROM entry
GROUP BY entryName, weight
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

When you find duplicated then you can delete them. If you want to delete them with query, then you can use something like this:

```
DELETE FROM entry
WHERE entryID IN (
    SELECT e.entryID 
    FROM entry AS e
    GROUP BY e.entryName, e.weight
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```